# Select element has two specific children using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select the parent by matching two children.
My code:

```js
$('span:contains("11:00am"), span.name:contains("Tom")').parents("a").css("background-color","rgb(255, 255, 255)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <div class="time">
    <span>11:00am</span>
  </div>
  <span class="name">Tom</span>
</a>
<a style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <div class="time">
    <span>11:00am</span>
  </div>
  <span class="name">Jack</span>
</a>
```

However this will select both **Tom** and **Jack**'s time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select `a` tag and then use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to filtering element has specific childs.

```
$('a:has(span:contains("11:00am")):has(span.name:contains("Tom"))')
```

```js
$('a:has(span:contains("11:00am")):has(span.name:contains("Tom"))').css("background-color","rgb(255, 255, 255)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <div class="time">
    <span>11:00am</span>
  </div>
  <span class="name">Tom</span>
</a>
<a style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <div class="time">
    <span>11:00am</span>
  </div>
  <span class="name">Jack</span>
</a>
```

Comment: :has() selector is what I am looking for, thank you, work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('span:contains("11:00am"),span:contains("Jack")').parent("a").css("background-color", "Grey");
$('span:contains("11:00am"),span:contains("Tom")').parent("a").css("background-color", "Green");
```

```html
<a style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="time">
    <span>11:00am</span>
  </div>
  <span class="name">Tom</span>
</a>

<a style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="time">
    <span>11:00am</span>
  </div>
  <span class="name">Jack</span>
</a>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: @Mohammad thanks your answer increase my knowledge too :)